# Laptop resolution on external monitor?

Tags: laptop, display, resolution, hdmi, external-display

I own Compaq CQ62 15.6" with Intel HD Graphics card, its max resolution is 1366 x 786, I like to increase the resolution but the only option which I figured out is to get an external monitor, I have seen **Samsung SyncMaster B2230H LCD TFT 22" HDMI Monitor** with 1920 X 1080 resolution.
But I need to confirm that if I connect the monitor with HDMI cable to my Laptop, will the monitor work on 1920 x 1080 resolution or laptop will will display 1366 x 786 resolution on the monitor?

Thanks

Comment: That depends on too many variables to list, including display drivers etc. Best advice is to bring your laptop to the shop and try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you attempt to clone the laptop screen to the external monitor, you will only get 1366x766, however, if you use the external monitor as either extend or as the only monitor, you will get 1920x1080.

Please note that the laptop screen resolution should be in the specifications when you buy it - unlike CRT monitors, flat panels are made up of a set amount of pixels and whilst you can choose a lesser total and "stretch" (or letterbox), you can never go bigger than the total (excluding on a few graphics cards which allow panning - but this is rare now).

Comment: so you mean to say that when I connect external monitor, I should select the mode which turns off the native laptop screen and only external monitor is used, and by doing that I can set my resolution to 1920x1080? correct me if  I am wrong

Comment: Yes, or, you can extend the screen so you can have two independent monitors, one at 1366x786 and the other at 1920x1080 - having different windows open on each... Once you start with multi screens, you won't want to go back!